# Holiday Home - Displaying the owner's who is signed in properties

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
 $queryread = "SELECT Properties.ID, Properties.Name, 
                      Properties.Description, County.County
               FROM Properties 
                    INNER JOIN County ON Properties.County_ID = County.ID 
                                     AND Properties.Ban = 0";
```

This is the query to display properties on the public website. When an owner is signed in how would i display only the properties that the owner owns.

Owner table is called "RegisteredOwners" and id is "id", there is also a "Owner_ID" in the Properties table.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML or HTML5. Don't tag it with things that don't matter, it clutters up search results.

Comment: Well you will have to write a new query, and the emphasis here is **YOU** will have to .....

Answer (score 0):

You will simply need to add a `WHERE` clause to your query. To keep the answer simple and contained, I'll just use a subquery for the where clause. The query below is identical to yours, with an added line for the where clause.

```
SELECT Properties.ID, Properties.Name, Properties.Description, County.County
FROM Properties INNER JOIN County ON (Properties.County_ID = County.ID AND Properties.Ban = 0)
WHERE Properties.Owner_ID = (SELECT id FROM RegisteredOwners WHERE Name=?)
```

You will need to replace the `Name=?` portion with the appropriate method of identifying the user's RegisteredOwners row.

Comment: make a separate query calling owner table and get row id?

Comment: The subquery in the last line is the query to get the row id. If you know how to build a query to get the row ID from RegisteredOwners, you can replace the subquery with the query you use to get the row's id value.